# QGIS 2.0 64bit Orfeo Toolbox Installation Failure

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, 64bit, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to install OTB in with QGIS 2.0.1 (Dufour) in Windows 7, 64bit.  I have no problem installing QGIS either the QGIS installer or OSGeo4W, but I have no luck with the OTB tools such as pansharpening etc.

Are the otb-gin etc. tools only available on the 32bit version?  Does anyone know if it is possible to install on the 64bit?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77462/configure-orfeo-toolbox-to-work-with-qgis-v2-windows-7-from-standalone-installer

Answer (score 5):

You are right that orfeo toolbox is not yet available in the 64 bit Version of OSGeo4w installer. You can compare the package listings here:

http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/x86/versions.html

http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/x86_64/versions.html

The 64-bit version is still experimental, with packages missing or not working as expected.

However, it is possible to use the 32-bit installer to install orfeo toolbox in C:\OSGeo4W (while the 64bit QGIS is in C:\OSGeo4w64), and nethertheless enter the paths to otb in 64-bit QGIS 2:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\orfeotoolbox\applications
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
```

This even works with the standalone installers.

---

**UPDATE**

According to http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/versions_diff-x86-x86_64.html both 32bit and 64 bit version of OSGEO4W now include the Orfeo Toolbox

The paths have to be entered in `Processing -> Options -> Providers -> Orfeo Toolbox` behind `OTB appication folder` and `OTB command line tools folder`. Doubleclick beneath `Value` reveals an input line with a three-dot-icon, which lets you navigate to the folder.

Comment: When you say 'enter the paths', how is this done? Through a menu in QGIS?

Comment: See my extended answer.