# Configure Orfeo Toolbox to work with QGIS v2 Windows 7 from standalone installer

Tags: qgis, installation, orfeo-toolbox

I have asked this question on the QGIS mailing list, but have not yet had a satisfactory result.

The QGIS manual at http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html
is confusing about how OTB and QGIS work together and how to install them.

On the one hand, it indicates that the OTB files are installed as part of the standalone installation package. But then goes on to tell us what the file paths (in the Options and Configuration area) for the OSGEO4 installer.

My installation, on a Win 7 64 bit machine, was done via the standalone installer. I can see the various algorithms under Processing, but none of the OTB ones work. They all render an error that says that OTB is not configured correctly.

Because I haven't installed via the OSGEO4 installer, I can't use the file paths that are outlined on the above page.

All I can tell is that 'it should work' out of the box, but that's not my experience. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing QGIS Dufour standalone, I have not found any path with orfeotoolbox files. Just because you see the menu entries in the plugin, it does not mean they are already installed.

The otb website recommends to install it via OSGEO4W installer. So even if you want to use QGIS standalone, you are encouraged to install otb with the OSGeo4W system, and add the paths

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\orfeotoolbox\applications
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
```

in your standalone version of QGIS as mentioned in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/otb-users/pfu4CQsHv18.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andre.  I can't see that it will help me. I am in an organisation where the IT staff have VERY strict control over what goes on PCs and they don't like the OSGEO installer and don't want to use it. So the standalone installer is the only option I have. It seems that there is an effort to integrate, more tightly, these components, so I may just have to wait.

Comment: Running the installation on another pc and just copying the folders from one PC to another (or using a USB stick as external drive) should work too.

Answer (score 1):

you can install otb without any admin rights on windows PC.

OTB distributes standalone packages in zip archives. Extract them and update setting otb processing plugin's settings to new path.

Since version 5.2.0, there is no update of osgeo4w packages for OTB. Users who use OSGeo4W are stuck with 5.0 version. So if you want new releases of OTB then you should use binary packages from OTB and not from OSGeo4W.

If you only want to run is some otb applications then you can do it without qgis processing. try mapla.bat which is otb's UI application launcher.  This is incase your admin does not allow to install qgis via OSGeo4W

UPDATE:

Here is the new otb-provider-plugin for QGIS 3.2
https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin

Things are stable now on OTB side and QGIS side and provider will be merged back to qgis core